# Remove unwanted values from the output values

Tags: powershell

I wrote the following script to list the services of a particular application. It runs fine but the command used in the script writes some unwanted output apart from the actual values. I need to strip out these unwanted values and print only the data that I want.

```
$InfaPrm = Import-Csv 'D:\Tools\InfaRestart\infa_parm.csv'

ForEach ($Params in $InfaPrm){
    $DOM = $Params.Domain
    $AdmUser= $Params.User
    $AdmPwd = $Params.Password
    $Security=$Params.SecurityDomain
    Set-Location -Path D:\Informatica\PowerCenter\isp\bin
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat Listservices"  -dn "$DOM" -un "$AdmUser" -sdn "$Security" -st "IS"}

}
```

Output:

```
INT_SVC_TEST
Command ran successfully.
INT_SVC_FIN_TEST
Command ran successfully.
INT_SVC_MAN_TEST
INT_SVC_HR_TEST
INT_SVC_EM_TEST
Command ran successfully.
```

I want to remove the string 'Command ran successfully.' from the above output and print only the service names.

Comment: you can simply use the `.Replace()` string method to replace the unwanted text with nothing OR you can use the `-replace` operator to do the same. it uses regex, so it should be somewhat faster if you have a large number of such items to remove.

Comment: another way would be to split on the spaces and take the 1st item in the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Replace string worked for my requirement. And Where-Object worked even better since it removed all the spaces between the output values.

Comment: you are most welcome ... glad to have helped a little bit! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It doesn't make sense to repeatedly set the same location,
  move that command in front of the foreach
- store outcome of `Invoke-Command` in a variable and suppress output of unwanted lines
  or directly append the `| Where-Object` to the `Invoke-Cmmand`

---

```
$InfaPrm = Import-Csv 'D:\Tools\InfaRestart\infa_parm.csv'
Set-Location -Path D:\Informatica\PowerCenter\isp\bin

ForEach ($Params in $InfaPrm){
    $DOM = $Params.Domain
    $AdmUser= $Params.User
    $AdmPwd = $Params.Password
    $Security=$Params.SecurityDomain
    $Output = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat Listservices"  -dn "$DOM" -un "$AdmUser" -sdn "$Security" -st "IS"}
    $Output | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Command ran successfully.'}
}
```

If that doesn't exclude the lines try with `-notlike` and a wildcard or `-notmatch` and a Regular Expression.

Comment: I am wondering how to capture the output from $Cmd into an array and loop through each line from the output to run another command. 
INT_SVC_TEST
INT_SVC_FIN_TEST
INT_SVC_MAN_TEST
INT_SVC_HR_TEST
INT_SVC_EM_TEST

Comment: Simply append a `| ForEach-Object {$_}` and do whatever you want with `$_`